How do I compare two sheets in excel and if there is a match copy and paste the description (cell associated to the match)?
Sheet 1:



PO NUM
Comments




51773



51775



51777




Sheet 2:



PO NUM
Comments




51777
xyz


63814
abc


51773
ghi


63814
def


51775
jkl



I am having trouble getting the PO Number to search and match between the sheets and then apply the comment from the matching PO num to sheet 1. Please Help!!
I have tried VLOOKUP, XLOOKUP, INDEX and MATCH but it is not searching the PO Number from the next sheet even though the numbers match.

Please post the formula you have tried,  Those three should work, unless one is stored as a number and the other as text that look like a number.

=INDEX('Sheet2 '!$J$1:J224,MATCH(Sheet1!M6,Sheet2!$F$3:$F$240,0))                                                         ==VLOOKUP(Sheet1!A2,Sheet2!A2:B28,1,FALSE)

=VLOOKUP(Sheet1!A2,Sheet2!A2:B28,2,FALSE) and if that does not work then your data does not match.

I think @ScottCraner is totally right, I just would add that Sheet2!A2:B28 should be an absolute reference in case you drag down the formula and it should be Sheet2!$A$2:$B$28. If those numbers are right aligned in cell means Excel is reading them as numbers but if they are left aligned then Excel is reading them as text, just in case you want to check it out.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

In MS365 it's as simple as =XLOOKUP(A2:A4,Sheet2!A2:A6,Sheet2!B2:B6).

Given your data schema, paste this formula in Sheet 1 B2
=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(Sheet1!A2,Sheet2!A:B,2,FALSE),"Not Found")
Once you see "ghe" populate in Sheet 1 B2 then apply the formula to the following rows by dragging from the bottom right of the cell to the end of your data or just double clicking on the bottom right corner.
Explanation
VLOOKUP:
The VLOOKUP formula looks for the Purchase Order number from Sheet1 in Sheet2. If it finds a match, it returns the corresponding description from column B of Sheet2.
IFERROR: This handles cases where a Purchase Order from Sheet1 doesn't exist in Sheet2, displaying "Not Found."
:)
P.S. This does look like test data created just for this question. Be mindful VLOOKUP cannot look to the left of the key field. In this case, use MATCH to find where the item is located, then use INDEX to retrieve the lookup value. Here is a great quick video explaining this situation, Search in YouTube for the title: "Excel - Can VLOOKUP Go to the Left? - Episode 2029"
